# strict topology on multiplier algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra,$M(A)$ is the multiplier algebra.If $S$ is a subset of $M(A)$ which is compact for the strict topology on $M(A)$,is $S$ also a subset of $M(M(A))$ which is compact for the strict topology on $M(M(A))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $M(A)$ is unital, so $M(M(A))=M(A)$.

Comment: Like I said, with the usual definitions the multiplier algebra of $M(A)$ is $M(A)$, since $M(A)$ is unital. This is simply the fact that the multiplier algebra of a unital $A$ is $A$: if $x\in M(A)$, then $x=x\,1\in A$.

Comment: I guess. It's confusing, because $M(M(A))$ doesn't really make sense to be mentioned as it's just $M(A)$.

Comment: I still don't know what you are talking about. You have $M(M(A))=M(A)$, so I don't really know what you mean when you talk about different things in two algebras that are the same.